# iptables https перенаправление на nodejs (правило)

Tags: linux, node.js, iptables, маршрутизация

Здравствуйте! подскажите как указать правило для `iptables` перенаправлять все `https` запросы на `nodejs`?

для http сделано так

**iptables**

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to 127.0.0.1:3000
```

**nodejs**

```
app.route('/*').get(function(req, res) {
  logreq(req);
  //res.send("");
});

function logreq(req){

  var method  = req.method
    , len = 10 - +method.length
    , met = new Array(len).join(" ");

  console.log("\n \033[32m ",me+met,"\033[42m\033[0m",
              "\033[33m hostname: \033[42m\033[0m",req.headers.host,
              "\033[32m Pathname: \033[42m\033[0m",req.url)
};

var server = app.listen(3000, '127.0.0.1', function(){

});
```

Comment: а ваш сервер, реализованный с помощью node.js, готов принимать соединения по протоколу https?

Comment: пока нет, если реализовать то в iptables --dport 80 поменять на --dport 443?

Comment: да, если сервер будет принимать https на том же порту номер 3000.

Comment: node.js не рекомендуется использовать напрямую, всегда должна быть прослойка в виде proxy-сервера, как минимум потому что node.js очень плох при обработке запросов к статическим файлам. Добавьте прослойку в виде nginx или apache. Proxy-сервер отработет https/ssl соединение, предоставит сертификат и данные полученные от node.js клиенту.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том, что *nodejs* будет слушать порт не по ssl, а подключение будет подразумевать использование ssl-шифрования. И браузер будет выдавать ошибку ssl, поскольку будет ждать ssl-handshake, но его не получит. Е

Если вам необходимо слушать именно https, то ознакомьтесь с примером в документации: https://nodejs.org/api/https.html